# Invalid login token. Missing a required claim: aud when accessing AWS Cognito AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've set up the user pool in Cognito and got the JWT token after authenticating the created user via cognito js sdk. And when I try to invoke the assumeRoleWithWebIdentity api it returns an error, below is the sample api call.

```
https://sts.amazonaws.com/
?Action=AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
&DurationSeconds=3600
&RoleSessionName=app1
&RoleArn=arn:aws:iam::id:role/_cross_account_role
&WebIdentityToken=jwtAccessToken
&Version=2011-06-15
```

The api response,

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>InvalidIdentityToken</Code>
<Message>Missing a required claim: aud</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>c01780d7-3705-11e8-80ef-533aa2d4f58f</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Would be great if I could know the root cause for this issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When the user is autheticated it gives an access token and ID token.

[image]

The issue occurs when you try to use the access token instead of the ID token.

Comment: I don't get it. I am trying to access a Backend API. We should never use idToken to access API services... :( https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis

Comment: I don't get it either but it solved my problem too ( using django-cognito-jwt in my environment )

Answer (score 4):

To further elaborate on Nirojan answer, it is because in the payload of `idToken` has the field of `aud` where else `accessToken` does not have `aud` in the payload hence the error of Missing required claimed: `aud`.